# Team Foundation Server Access to the Path ... is denied

Tags: tfs

I just got assigned at my job to figuring out Team Foundation Server as we are switching to it from PVCS.  I was messing around with the source control features, trying to get gated check-in to work, as that is something we will be using in my job.  I am pretty sure I set up the build definition correctly, as far as I can tell that is, and I turned MSBuild Multi-Proc to false as I have seen suggested online.

My problem is that when I try to check in a file I get an error for every file in my project stating

`C:\Builds\1\TFSTestProject\Gated\src\TFSTestPrograms\TFSTestPrograms\{File} Access to the path 'C:\Builds\1\TFSTestProject\Gated\src\TFSTestPrograms\TFSTestPrograms' is denied.`

I don't understand why I would have any access denied and I have looked for solutions all over google and have not found anything that has fixed this issue. My server url is just `http://localhost:8080/tfs` so I should have access to everything (at least I think i should...)

Another thing is that there is no 'Builds' folder on my C:\ drive like in the path they give

I am very confused about this issue and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: If you are going to work on a project locally, why do you need tfs? You can use http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs it is free and allows other users to connect as well.

Comment: This is just me trying to learn TFS, it will not be for local projects in the future, just for learning purposes.  My bosses want me to learn TFS so that I can demo it to my coworkers and show them how to use it when we make the switch from PVCS within the next couple of weeks.  So I am just trying to get as much experience with it as possible but thank you for that link that could be useful for some things I'm working on at home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed a build server the path that it is objecting to is on the build server itself. You should review the installation instructions for the build server and the account used to set up the build server.

Two lengthy to repost but ben day has an excellent TFS installation guide here: http://www.benday.com/BlogFiles/Tfs2012InstallGuide/BenDay-TFS2012-Install-Guide-v1.0.pdf

Comment: Thank you I am going to try that out

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that whatever account you configured TFS and, more importantly, the Team Build service to run as, has full control access to the C:\Builds folder.

Comment: My problem is that there is no Builds folder directly on C:\ 
Even though I've made sure that hidden files and folders are visible

Comment: Well that root folder needs to be there, so just create it now.  It was a location that you were supposed to create/configure when you setup the Team Build Agents.

Comment: OK, I figured it needed to be there I just thought surely I would'nt be the one responsible for creating it.  But I will definitely give it a try! thanks